# Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_93: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm

My X_train shape is (171,10,1) and y_train shape is (171,)(contains values from 1 to 19).
The output should be probability of each of the 19 class.
I am trying to use a RNN for classification of 19 classes.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
label_encoder_X=LabelEncoder()
label_encoder_y=LabelEncoder()

y_train=label_encoder_y.fit_transform(y_train)
y_train=np.array(y_train)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout


regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True, input_shape=( 
(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(rate=0.15))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences =False))#False caused the 
exception ndim
regressor.add(Dropout(rate=0.15))


regressor.add(Flatten())
regressor.add(Dense(units= 19,activation='sigmoid'))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 250, batch_size = 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `return_sequences =False` in the second LSTM layer, the result is that (None, 100) no longer needs `Flatten()`. You can set `return_sequences=True` in the second LSTM layer or delete `regressor.add(Flatten())` according to your needs.

In addition, if you want to get probability of each of the 19 class, your label data should be in one-hot form. Using `keras.utils.to_categorical`:

```
one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=19) #(None,19)
regressor.fit(X_train, one_hot_labels, epochs = 250, batch_size = 16)
```

Comment: Thanks . I tried that snippet of code. But when I run the `keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=19)` in the interpreter, It throws a different **error index 20 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 19**. Can you please help out. I am not being able to rectify it.

However, when I give the `num_classes=21` , the program executes just fine . But considering I have only 19 labels , I think it would not be valid to run it that way.

Comment: @Suvab This error indicates that there is a number of 20 in your `y_train`. You should make sure that label number in `y_train` belongs to `[0,18]`.