# Neural Network model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have sample data with 6 columns and 100 rows (all values are integers). there are 20 classes that the input data is classified into. This is the model that I tried building:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50,input_shape=X.shape[1:],activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(20,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
predictions=model.predict(test_data)
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (20,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Can you give me a proper architecture for this?

Comment: What's the shape of `Y`?

Comment: @giser_yugang it's (60,). I am new to neural networks.. is there something I am doing wrong>

Comment: Your label data should be in one-hot form. Using `keras.utils.to_categorical`. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874013/input-0-is-incompatible-with-layer-lstm-93-expected-ndim-3-found-ndim-2/53879696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `Y` to a binary class matrix using `to_categorical` ([docs](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical)).

```
import sklearn.datasets
X,Y = sklearn.datasets.make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=6, n_redundant=0,n_informative=6, n_classes=20)

import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50,input_dim=X.shape[1],activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(20,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X, to_categorical(Y), epochs=1000, verbose=1) # <---
```

Also you can use [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) for that too.